# Wireshark capture filter - shorter ways to define drop lists of ip6 addresses?

Tags: wireshark

Is there some shorter way to define a long list of ip6 addresses to drop as Wireshark *capture* (not *display*) filter?

Shorter than capture filters like these, I mean:

```
host <wanted-ip6-addr> and not host <unwanted-ip6-addr1> and not host <unwanted-ip6-addr2>
```

```
host <wanted-ip6-addr> && ! host <unwanted-ip6-addr1> && ! host <unwanted-ip6-addr2>
```

Is there maybe something that works like:

```
NOT IN [<comma separated list of ip6 addresses>]
```

Also, for IPv6 addresses of the same subnet, I tried IPv6 CIDR similar to this:

```
host <wanted-ip6-addr> and not host 2001:db8::/46
```

but this does not seem to be supported, or is no valid syntax; can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*Also, for IPv6 addresses of the same subnet, I tried IPv6 CIDR similar to this:*

Have you tried something like this (untested) filter?

```
ip6 and host <wanted-ip6-addr> and not (((ip6[8:4] = 0x20010db8) and ((ip6[12:2] & 0xfffc) = 0)) or ((ip6[24:4] = 0x20010db8) and ((ip6[28:2] & 0xfffc) = 0)))
```